# comparing two lists creates an error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make the program print smaller numbers than it did previously this error doesnt make any sense as im comparing two lists not an int and a list?

```
    else:
        if len(tuple(guessstore)) == 3:
            if guessstore[1] > code[1]:    
                randomnumber2 = random.randint(0,9 < guessstore[1])
            elif guessstore[1] < code[1]:    
                randomnumber2 = random.randint(0,9 > guessstore[1])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Further Programming\Assignment3\number2.py", line 153, in <module>
    ch2()
  File "F:\Further Programming\Assignment3\number2.py", line 82, in ch2
    if guessstore[1] > code[1]:    #if code is larger than guess print that its larger
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

Please help. I don't know why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1):

looks like `guessstore[1]` is a list and `code[1]` is a int, maybe the error is in how you handle `guessstore` that make it a list of list, by the code you show, looks like `guessstore` is a list, if that is the case perhaps you do something like this `guessstore+=[[n]]` or `guessstore.append( [n] )` (where n in a number) that make you guard a list with n in it inside of `guessstore`, instead do `guessstore.append( n )`. Or equivalently in how you handle `code` that make it a list of int, with only that portion of the code that is all of what I can tell.